# Background Firebase Push Notification data handling

Tags: android, firebase, webview, push

I am a web developer and am trying to develop an application that basically is a Webview that can receive instructions through push requests to redirect the user to specific pages. It is already functional, I just need to correct an issue:

I have tried to make a function in the class that receives and processes the push information that updates the contents of the Webview. But there is some conflict and it is impossible to do so, because one class is static and the other not due to their inheritance.

The way I found around this was creating an string variable inside my "watch messages class" started with "EMPTY" value that receives the value sent in a specific field within the push request 'date' when the notification is clicked. There's my public class FireBaseWatchMessages that extends FirebaseMessagingService:

```
   public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d("LOG_ONRECEIVE_1", "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d("LOG_VALID_DATA", "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d("LOG_NULL_NOTIFICATION", "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        sendNotification(remoteMessage);
        if (data.containsKey("appReportedAction")) {
            Log.d("SET_ACTION", "/appReportedAction/" + data.get("appReportedAction"));
            NEW_URL_FROM_ACTION = MainActivity.SSLPROTOCOL + "://" + MainActivity.MAIN_URL +"/appReportedAction/" + data.get("appReportedAction");
        }
    }
```

In my MainActivity there's a function to change webview content. It works like this:

```
public void changeViewContent(String actionView){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        if(FireBaseWatchMessages.NEW_URL_FROM_ACTION != "EMPTY"){
            mWebView.loadUrl(FireBaseWatchMessages.NEW_URL_FROM_ACTION);
        } else {
            mWebView.loadUrl( SSLPROTOCOL + "://" + MAIN_URL + actionView);
        }
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    }
```

So when the application opens it checks if this variable has a value other than "EMPTY", if so Webview opens the modified URL according to its value, not the default URL.

It happens that when the application is closed when clicking on the message sent by the push the URL doesn't open with the appropriate modifications, as if the variable was not really receiving the value sent by the push.

Using the app debugger I noticed that its log commands do not appear on the console when it is not open, which makes me believe that the function does not really run when the application is closed.

Any idea how I can correct this behavior? How can I make the action of clicking the notification send the parameter to the webview?

Comment: Have you handled the notification click? Using intents?

Comment: Clarify the question! Show more code?

Answer (score 0):

I want to first say that your approach is uncommon and I do not recommend storing url in such a manner, since services can be killed/stopped (by user or device) and so you lose your data or the device was turned off so you lose your data. So instead of using variables I have made two methods using Shared Preferences its easy and the storage is permanent in the device even when your app is not in use!

**HERE HOW:**
The first method is:

```
    public boolean addNewUrl(Context context, String url) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("SHARED URL", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("url", url);
    return editor.commit();
}
```

Define the first method in the `FireBaseWatchMessages` and it stores the URL and returns `true` if successfully stored.

And the second is:

```
    public String getUrlAndSetEmpty(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("SHARED URL", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    String current_url = sharedPref.getString("url", "EMPTY");
    editor.putString("url", "EMPTY");
    editor.apply();
    return current_url;
}
```

Define this in the `MainActivity` to get Url returned and also sets the url to "EMPTY" after its takes it!

The first method will be called from the Service FireBaseWatchMessages. This will accept context which for our case it is `this` or `FireBaseWatchMessages.this` and it will also accept a URL in form of a string so change your URL into a `String`. It will then store it in your app internal storage as `url`!

So just call:

```
    addNewUrl(this,your_url_string);
```

The second method will be called in the `MainActivity` or any activity that you want it to work. So define it in the `MainActivity`. What it does it check if there is a url stored in the storage if it doesn't find any it returns String `"EMPTY"` and if it finds it it returns it as a current url and also change the value of the stored String to empty because it has already got one. So just call:

```
    String url= getUrlAndSetEmpty(this);
```

And cheers the url returned can be a really URL STRING OR just a String "EMPTY". Handle the Logic.

This is the best APPROACH for your case! It works any time! It does not depend if the app is visible on foreground  or not!

Check your code if you handled the intent correctly on Activity creation!

But also in java when we compare Objects( `String` included) we use the (`Object1.equals(Object2)`) instead of (`=`) sign. So change the line where you called:

```
     if(FireBaseWatchMessages.NEW_URL_FROM_ACTION != "EMPTY")
```

Change to:

```
     if(!((FireBaseWatchMessages.NEW_URL_FROM_ACTION).equals("EMPTY")))
```

Do not forget the `!` sign there in the condition!

If that doesn't work check the Intent you used to start the `Activity`.

Comment: So, let me clarify things: the string checking and URL changing is OK (still thanks for the tip). The problem itself is that if the application is closed the variable (NEW_URL_FROM_ACTION) does not get the value of the parameter I am sending with Firebase, nor does it occur when the application is opened with the click action in the notification.